# R: Looping custom function with paired variables?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am comparing scores from specific columns in Site_Compile:

```
tail(Site_Compile)
       Node_10_State Node_11_State Node_12_State 
19231             0             1             -             
19232             1             1             1             
19233             0             0             0             
19234             0             0             0             
19235             0             0             0            
19236             1             1             1
```

using the following block per new column:

```
Gain_Loss_Track$Node2_vs_Node3 <- ifelse(Site_Compile$Node_2_State == '-' | Site_Compile$Node_3_State == '-', '?',
                                    ifelse(Site_Compile$Node_2_State < Site_Compile$Node_3_State, 'Loss',
                                        ifelse(Site_Compile$Node_2_State > Site_Compile$Node_3_State, 'Gain',
                                            ifelse(Site_Compile$Node_2_State == Site_Compile$Node_3_State, 'Same', 'Other'))))
```

to generate a new dataframe which looks like this:

```
tail(Gain_Loss_Track)
             X_vs_Node1  Node1_vs_Node2   Y_vs_Node2    Node2_vs_Node3  
19231              Same           Same        Same           Same      
19232              Same           Same        Same           Same      
19233              Loss           Same        Same           Same      
19234              Loss           Same        Same           Same      
19235              Same           Same        Same           Same      
19236              Same           Same        Same           Same
```

I would love to loop this to save space (and room for error) but need to only compare specific pairs of columns from the dataset, I don't want to loop through making all comparisons. The pairs aren't always neat (I couldn't automate with comparing i and i+1 pairs or any regular pattern, I have to list the pairs to compare somehow).

I think I should be able to do this with a for loop using some custom function but am stuck on how to loop with many paired variables.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data, eg. through head(), or str()?

Comment: hope the edits are helpful!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a `Node_2_State` column, even though your function references it. And where do X and Y come from? Possibly look into `case_when`, as it is made for such situations. You could try giving us a `dput(head(df))` of the full dataframe, and listing all of the pairs you want in a separate dataframe. That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry, these are samples as I've done this manually already making 37 comparisons using the Site_Compile df which has a total of 39 columns- just wanted to post examples of generally what the df looks like. 
```
I'm less worried about condensing the line of code I have listed and more concerned with how to loop my specific comparisons  (not always neighbors, not fitting any pattern, I need to list the pairs somehow) through these 4 ifelse statements- or achieve this by some similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution using `fcase()`.

#### For one pair of columns

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Site_Compile)

compare_columns <- function(x,y){
  fcase(x == '-' | y == '-', "?",
        x < y, 'Loss',
        x > y, 'Gain',
        x == y, 'Same', 
        default = 'Other')
}

Site_Compile[, Node2_vs_Node3 := compare_columns(Node_2_State, Node_3_State)]
```

#### For multiple pairs of columns

And then for multiple columns, you could do the following, modifying `compare_columns()` slightly:

```
compare_columns <- function(z, DT){
  x <- z[1]; y <- z[2]
  fcase(DT[[x]] == '-' | DT[[y]] == '-', "?",
        DT[[x]] < DT[[y]], 'Loss',
        DT[[x]] > DT[[y]], 'Gain',
        DT[[x]] == DT[[y]], 'Same', 
        default = 'Other')
}

new_col_names <- paste0("Node",1:10,"_vs_","Node",11:20)

data_column_pairs <- list(c("first_var1","first_var2"),
  c("second_var1","second_var2"), ...)

Site_Compile[, (new_col_names) := 
  lapply(data_column_pairs, compare_columns, DT = Site_Compile)]
```

For example, on the `mtcars` dataset,

```
data(mtcars)

library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)

data_column_pairs <- list(c("gear","carb"),
                          c("drat", "wt"),
                          c("mpg","qsec"))

new_col_names <- c("first","second","third")

mtcars[, (new_col_names) := lapply(data_column_pairs, compare_columns, DT = mtcars)]

mtcars
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb first second third
 1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Same   Gain  Gain
 2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Same   Gain  Gain
 3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  Gain   Gain  Gain
 4: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  Gain   Loss  Gain
 5: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  Gain   Loss  Gain
 6: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  Gain   Loss  Loss
 7: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  Loss   Loss  Loss
 8: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  Gain   Gain  Gain
 9: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  Gain   Gain  Loss
```

There is probably a nicer way to define `compare_columns()`, but I played around with it a bit and this is the first way I could get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, I used this almost exactly! 
All works except for the lapply step I have the error 
"Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, : 
object 'y' not found" :
I cannot find a y that I've listed that would need to be defined? I checked that all variables for lapply as well as the column names are defined. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @Amanda, How is your `data_column_pairs` equivalent structured? Is it a list of vectors? That is crucial to this working.

Comment: Yep, my pairs are structured so that 
GL_pairs <- list(c("Node_15_State","Node_2_State"), c("Node_3_State","Node_2_State"), c("Node_7_State","Node_3_State")...)

Comment: Is there a typo anywhere in GL_pairs? Also, are you using the second version of `compare_columns()`, where the arguments are `z` and `DT`?

Comment: I had a typo in one of the brackets for compare_columns(), fixed it and it works now! Thank you so much :-)